# Dual differential amplifier question

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

I am looking to design a high power amplifier that can amplify a 500 Hz, 20V signal to 80 V and power a 4 ohm load.

I have 2 ways of approaching this (using op amps):

1. Design 1 inverting buffer, and 2 inverting power amps, and have a differential output.
2. Design 1 inverting power op amp, and 1 non-inverting power op amp and have a differential output

See image for better explanation. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.[image]

Comment: You should explain what is preventing you from moving forward to a design. If you are unable to design an audio amplifier then consider buying one. Are you talking about RMS voltages?

Comment: I am talking peak to peak voltages. I am just looking to get some thoughts before I begin designing...

Comment: What is your load and why are you inverting? If driving a speaker or resistive load, the two opposite polarity outputs will cancel and no current will flow.

Comment: My load is a speaker. I am inverting because I do not have an 80 VPP power supply. My power supply is a 300W, 48V. and I need my output to be 80V.

Comment: Typically, you have 1 amp, that has a "phase splitter", followed by two drive sections.

Comment: 80 volts p-p is 28 volts RMS and, into 4 ohms, that's a power of 200 watts. You can buy an audio amplifier that does this. Look for a 200 watt bridge amplifier is my recommendation. You can probably find a module that does this and, at the operating frequency, a class D amplifier will be a suitable choice.

Comment: If driving a speaker or resistive load, the two opposite polarity outputs will cancel and no current will flow. -- No.  The two out-of-phase outputs will increase the load power by 4x over that of either output individually.  This is called BTL - Bridge-Tied Load.

Comment: BTL:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridged_and_paralleled_amplifiers

Answer (score 1):

It is always easier to use two identical power amplifiers.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with two identical power amps.  A low-level inverting stage is very simple, and two identical power stages means that if something needs to be changed/updated/tweaked, the change is identical in both.